# How do I create an Azure API Management instance via C#?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I've been using the Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent packages to create a tool that will build out my environment and do some additional setup. Now, I need to add an API Management instance. I don't see anything related to API Management in the Fluent SDK. I'm assuming there's no SDK wrapper for it and I just need to make the REST calls myself. I'm looking for a guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, `API Management` is not supported in the `Fluent api`. Here is an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/issues/580) about this.

Instead, there is another package [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApiManagement 6.0.0-preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApiManagement/), you can use it to create `API Management instance`. The code like below:

```
        // you should provide the real credentialhere.
        ApiManagementClient client = new ApiManagementClient(the_credential);

        //provide the neccesary parameters to create the APIM instance.
        client.ApiManagementService.CreateOrUpdate(the_parameters);
```

**Another way** to create `API Management` is by using this api: [Api Management Service - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/apimanagementservice/createorupdate). You can read the api doc for its usage and examples.

Comment: The preview package is nice. I'm converting to this as it simplifies a bunch of configuration that I need to do after the API manager is created. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with REST:
[Deployments - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/deployments/createorupdate)

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/{deploymentName}?api-version=2020-06-01
```

You have to pass the link to your [ARM Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/overview) in the Request-Body:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "templateLink": {
      "uri": "https://example.com/exampleTemplate.json"
    },
    "parameters": {},
    "mode": "Complete",
    "onErrorDeployment": {
      "type": "SpecificDeployment",
      "deploymentName": "name-of-deployment-to-use"
     }
   }
}
```

You can store the ARM Template in Blob Storage and reference it in the Body.

Please find a sample API-Management ARM Template on [GitHub - azure-quickstart-templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-azure-api-management-create)

Comment: Thanks, yes this worked for me using the IAzure.Deployments fluent API to run the ARM template, but I now have the problem of not being able to check for existence, so I may have to go REST with the ARM template in blob storage.